# Setting up Symfony with Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

I'm in the dev environment and I have preference on using Apache instead of symfony default server.

I installed symfony/apache-pack as suggested in documentation but my app is currently under public folder - `http://localhost/SITENAME/public/`.
I.e. If I type `http://SITENAME` in a browser I get a list of folder structure which I believe is unsafe. Will adding `.htaccess` "Options -Indexes" rule file inside root folder fixes the problem?

I believe the default path shoot be: `http://localhost/SITENAME` or `http://localhost/SITENAME/route-name`. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi)?

Comment: I'm using xampp. I don't really understand that part. Do i need to copy the code and place it somewhere ?

Comment: If you have “a preference for using Apache”; maybe you should familiarize yourself with the software. If you are out of tour depth with Apache, use the built in server to learn the ropes.

Comment: I was trying do it  but i ran into command prompt not recognizing symfony commands for some reason. Ok so far I can develop my app with the having the /public in url locally, otherwise it works fine, but will it mean I will ran into problems later one when passing the app onto production ?